# Close ResultSet after using in catch-block

Tags: java, jdbc

Eclipse IDE always shows following warning:

> Resource leak: 'rset' is not closed at this location

But for me the code seems to be correct:

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;
try {
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        String query = foo();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String query = bar();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    }
    return JsonHandler.resultSetToJson(rset);
} finally {
    if (rset != null)
        rset.close();
    if (stmt != null)
        stmt.close();
}
```

How do I close the ResultSet?

Comment: you are overwriting previous `rset` in catch block - that is the reason.

Comment: Your IDE is actually wrong.  ResultSets are a special case.  From [the ResultSet documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html):  “A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73209155/close-resultset-after-using-in-catch-block/73209834#comment129295510_73209155), your second assignment of `rset` would let the first `ResultSet` object become a candidate for garbage collection without being closed. Thus the warning from the compiler or your IDE.

To more reliably and clearly close your resources, use try-with-resources.

## try-with-resources syntax

Modern Java offers the try-with-resources syntax feature to automatically close any object that implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) with its single method `close`. The resources will be closed in the reverse of the order in which they were instantiated. And they are closed whether your code completes successfully or throws an exception.

See [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) provided free of cost by Oracle Corp.

Try-with-resources is one of my favorite features in Java. Along with [text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378), database work is much easier now, and more fool-proof.

`Connnection`, `Statement`, and `ResultSet` are all such auto-closeable resources. So wrap them in try-with-resource syntax.

### Exceptions

Get specific with your exceptions. Trap for the ones expected within the local context.

### Code

Here is some untested code.

Notice how we name each `ResultSet` object differently.

Notice how the nesting of try-with-resources calls communicates visually the cascading structure of our logic.

```java
try 
(
    Connection conn = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
)
{
    try 
    (
        ResultSet rsetFoo = stmt.executeQuery( foo() );
    )
    {
        return JsonHandler.resultSetToJson( rsetFoo );
    }
    catch ( SQLException | SQLTimeoutException e) 
    {
        try 
        (
            ResultSet rsetBar = stmt.executeQuery( bar() );
        )
        {
            return JsonHandler.resultSetToJson( rsetBar );
        }
    }
}
catch ( SQLException e ) 
{
    … 
}
catch ( SQLTimeoutException e ) 
{
    …
}
```

If you had searched before posting, you would have found many existing examples, and much discussion, already posted on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use **try-with-resources** feature

You can use `try-with-resources` feature of `java 7` it will handle the auto closing of the resources as `ResultSet`,`Statement` implements `AutoCloseable` interface.

like : `try (ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query))`

similarly for other resources as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the `return`statement after the `finally` clause. i think your function is ignoring everything that comes after the `return` statement.

Try something like :

```
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;

String parsedResult = null;  // String or the object type you want to return.

try {
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    try {
        String query = foo();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String query = bar();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    }
     parsedResult = JsonHandler.resultSetToJson(rset);
} finally {
    if (rset != null)
        rset.close();
    if (stmt != null)
        stmt.close();
}

return parsedResult;
```